# Does this monadic parser cause space leaks?

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, arrows

I was reading the arrow tutorial.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_arrows#Avoiding_leaks.
And I got confused reading this part

```hs
solfege :: Parser Char String
solfege = string "Do" <|> string "Re" <|> string "Mi"
```

> Through this last example, we can indicate which issue Swierstra and Duponcheel were trying to tackle. When solfege is run on the string "Fa", we can't detect the parser will fail until all of the three alternatives have failed. If we had more complex parsers in which one of the alternatives might fail only after attempting to consume a lot of the input stream, we would have to descend down the chain of parsers in the very same way. All of the input that can possibly be consumed by later parsers must be retained in memory in case one of them happens to be able to consume it. That can lead to much more space usage than you would naively expect − a situation often called a space leak.

I don't understand that `solfege` has risk of causing space leaks. Every alternative in `solfege`(`string "Do"`, `string "Re"`, and `string "Mi"`) fails on the comparison with 'F', the first character of "Fa". If these alternatives consume more than one character and fail, then I can accept that `solfege` causes space leaks. However, that's only possible when `string`'s implementation is dumb. Also, it's hard for me to imagine a monadic parser that fails late after consuming unnecessary tokens, unless it's poorly written on purpose.

Am I missing something in the article?

Comment: "If we had more complex parsers in which one of the alternatives might fail only after attempting to consume a lot of the input stream"

Comment: As Cubic notes, `solfege` itself is not meant to be an example of a leaking parser, but just to suggest how this pattern of using `(<|>)` might give rise to leaks when used with different subparsers. That said, perhaps the simplified example that section of the page uses to illustrate the Swierstra and Duponcheel approach is too simple to get the point across in an effective way. (On a meta note, I have reviewed that part of the page a long time ago, but mostly worked on making the text clearer, leaving the substance largely unchanged. Second best time is now, I guess :))

Comment: I've invested more about space leaks in the monadic parser, and now I think I understand when the leaks happen.
For example, `many digit <|> string "foo"` on a long string of digits will leak because the `many digit` parser will consume all the input, but the consumed digits can not be freed due to the possibiltiy of `many digit` to fail and backtrack to give a chance to `string "foo"`. But Arrow parser can rule out this possibility and knows that `many digit` is the only option, so it can free the consumed digits.
Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @12412316 Yes, that's right.

Comment: @12412316 IMO, that's not a good example, since `many digit` either fails because of the first (non digit) char, or surely succeeds. E.g., on "123urk" it will succeed consuming 3 chars. Perhaps a better example is `(many digit >> string "end") <|> string "foo"`

Answer (score 1):

The key part that you probably glossed over is this bit:

> If we had more complex parsers in which one of the alternatives might fail only after attempting to consume a lot of the input stream, ...

So, `string "Do"` is not meant to be taken literally, but as standing in for a parser that does more work and may have to look arbitrarily far ahead in the input to know whether it should fail or not.